# Why is my VS code editor not running my code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have noticed that sometimes VS code does not run my code. The terminal appears something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PNo3.jpg. I tried running the same code in an online compiler and it worked just fine.

I want to know what's wrong with my compiler and how can I fix it.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

     int n;
     int arr[n];
     cout<<"Enter size of array: ";
     cin>>n;
     cout<<"Enter "<<n<<" elements of array: ";

     for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
     }

     for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code inside your `array_2.cpp` file into here. It's possible that your file does not output anything to the console

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect

```
 int n;
 int arr[n];
 cout<<"Enter size of array: ";
 cin>>n;
```

You are using the value of `n` **before** it has been given a value. This is better

```
 int n;
 cout<<"Enter size of array: ";
 cin>>n;
 int arr[n];
```

Incidentally, this construct is called a *variable length array* (VLA), as is not actually legal C++. In C++ array sizes must be constants, not variables. You are using a compiler that accepts VLAs (g++) but other compilers would correctly reject the code. Something to bear in mind.

The correct code in C++ would use a vector instead.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

     int n;
     cout<<"Enter size of array: ";
     cin>>n;
     vector<int> arr(n); // vector instead of VLA
     cout<<"Enter "<<n<<" elements of array: ";

     for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
     }

     for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
     }

     return 0;
}
```

That is legal C++ code, which would be accepted by any compiler.